# how can a find multiple values at once in an array php

Tags: php, arrays

trying to make a tic-tac-toe game actually. So if there's a better way I would like to know too!
So I have a grid [0,8], and the user's positions are stored in an array. Great.
Next I want to see if the columns match up. So let's say first row is (0,1,2). 
My question is if the user has an array like `array(1,5,6,0,2)`, so he won. How can I match it efficiently?
I was thinking of doing something like this but doesn't look efficient:

```
$user= array(1,5,6,0,2);
in_array(0,$user) && in_array(1,$user) && in_array(2,$user)
```

I also thought about switch case but still face the question how do I find multiple values at once.

Comment: You might use [`array_intersect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) to compare an array representing a row `[0,1,2]` with the user's array and verify the output of the intersection has `count() == 3`, meaning all 3 were matched. Among the expansive set of PHP [array functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) there are many which could be used to suit your needs one way or another.  Are you planning to keep a list of possible values that constitute a row (simple), or would you want those to be determined algorithmically (a little harder)?

Comment: This might be of interest: http://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~yosenl/extras/alphabeta/alphabeta.html

Comment: For a tic-tac-toe I would choose to operate with a two-dimensional matrix a.k.a. array, filled with three possible values 0 (unoccupied space), 1 (x) and -1 (o), and then count the sums for the rows, columns and diagonals.

Comment: TicTacToe is fairly simple since there are only 8 ways to win 3 horiz, 3 vert, 2 diag). Simply see if any of the 8 "winning" arrays are a subset of the `$user` array.

Comment: Thanks guys. I love all the answers, pretty interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that with such a small number of possible combinations to win, the solution can be kept very simple. I would do it using array_diff.

```
function has_won($user) {
    // returns false if the user has not won, otherwise 
    // returns the first winning combination found.
    $wins = [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8],[0,3,6],[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[0,4,8],[2,4,6]];
    foreach ($wins as $win) {
        if (!array_diff($win, $user)) return $win;
        // array_diff returns the values in the first argument
        // not present in any subsequent arguments. So if its 
        // result is empty, the user has winning combination.
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Note for future readers: using `empty()` directly in this context will require PHP 5.5. With 5.4 and below, it would be a parse error since the result of `array_diff()` is not a variable. The `array_diff()` would first need to be stored in a variable, in turn passed to `empty()`.  5.5 can operate on the result of an expression however.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Excellent point; thank you. I should mention that in the answer.

Comment: Why are you using `empty` here in the first place, especially when it requires all these caveats? Just write `!array_diff(..)`, it's the exact same thing!

Comment: @deceze Of course! That certainly does simplify things. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I will not make a claim that this is the *most* efficient method, but it reduces the number of operations considerably compared with `&&` chaining and multiple `in_array()` calls.

What we'll do is keep a 2-dimensional array of possible win-combinations: rows, columns, diagonals, as sub-arrays.  Then in a `foreach` loop over that 2D array, test the user's current array state against the row combination with [`array_intersect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php).  If the entire winning combination is present in the user's array, the result of `array_intersect()` will be 3, which you can test with `count()`.

Since one match is enough for a win, you can break out of the loop on the first match to declare a win.

```
$combinations = array(
  // Rows
  array(0,1,2),
  array(3,4,5),
  array(6,7,8),
  // Columns
  array(0,3,6),
  array(1,4,7),
  array(2,5,8),
  // Diagonals
  array(0,4,8),
  array(2,4,6),
);

// Loop over the array of winners and test array_intersect()
// If 3 values intersect, the full win combination was matched
foreach ($combinations as $combination) {
   if (count(array_intersect($combination, $user)) == 3) {
      // User wins! Take whatever action necessary...
      // Exit the loop
       break;
   }
}
```

Here's a demonstration in which 2 of 3 sets for `$user` are winners: http://codepad.viper-7.com/Mvu0wa

There are algorithmic ways of generating the winning combinations rather than hard-coding them, but there are only eight possible combinations so it isn't that hard, and the point here is the use of `array_intersect()` to find a subset of the user's current placements.